# How many $N$ digits binary numbers can be formed where $01$ exactly $k$ times is repeated.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many $N$ digits binary numbers can be formed where $01$ exactly $k$ times is repeated.

Note: first digit can't be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider our binary sequence from left to right.  It starts with the digit 1, and continues with 1's until there is a change.  Then we have a sequence of 0's, until the next change, when we get a sequence of 1's.  This continues until we get to the end of the sequence.

Note that every time we switch from a sequence of 0's to a sequence of 1's, we get a 01 pattern.  Hence this happens exactly $k$ times.  We must also change from 1's to 0's before each such switch, so there must be at least $2k$ switches.  There could be a $2k+1$st switch, depending on whether or not we end with a 0 or a 1.  However, there cannot be a $2k+2$nd switch, because that would give a $k+1$st 01 pattern, which is not allowed.

The switches can happen in any position after the first, leaving $N-1$ possible switch locations.

If there are $2k$ switches, there are $\binom{N-1}{2k}$ ways to choose where these switches occur.  If there are $2k+1$ switches, there are $\binom{N-1}{2k+1}$ ways of choosing the locations of the switches.  These each give distinct sequences, and so the answer is
$\binom{N-1}{2k} + \binom{N-1}{2k+1} = \binom{N}{2k+1}$.

Comment: This is a really clever solution! Cool work!

Comment: For some reason I thought the question asked for $6$ patterns - I have no idea why.  Thanks for pointing this out; I've changed the solution to the general case.